# Adding IOKit to iOS Project

Tags: iphone, iokit

I'm currently trying to add IOKit to my project. I linked against the IOKit dyn lib and linked against the provate header files. The problem is, that i get an error while building, as it says, that iokit dyn lib couldn't be found, but i linked against it.

Best regards

Header files from: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/IOKit.framework

Comment: Simulator or device build?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. On both. The iOS SDK is iOS 5. Is this a possible reason?

Comment: How did you get header files from that link? I dont see any downloadable header files there