# iOS 7 - Add IOKit and IOSurface to project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iokit, iosurface

I am making an iPhone app and it requires IOKit and IOSurface framework. I have included these frameworks in the project. When I expand the framework once it's linked, I can see the headers. However, when I try:

```
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>
#include <IOSurface/IOSurface.h>
```

...it says it cannot find the file. I am running Xcode 6 with the app targeted for iOS 7+.

I have also tried this:
[IOKit Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542092/iokit-not-found)
...and all that says is that the file was found after I run the command.

and this:
[symbol(s) not found in XCode, Cocoa application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159227/symbols-not-found-in-xcode-cocoa-application)

Both do not work for me. It looks like this person is having a similar problem, if it helps at all:
[Adding IOKit to iOS Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273638/adding-iokit-to-ios-project)